# Drop down list binding through ODBC in ASP.NET MVC and MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, odbc

**My problem:**

Trying to establish a connection through ODBC from visual studio (ASP.NET MVC project) to a remote server (Fishbowl) which uses MYSQL. Ultimate goal is to bind data from database to the drop down list. Instead of actually retrieving the rows from the column in query, I get output like this when I run the code:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? Any suggestions or alternate method? Thanks!

**Controller Connection Part**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (OdbcConnection connfb = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Fishbowl"))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select xyz from abc", connfb))
            {
                connfb.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.Fill(dt);
                da.Fill(ds);

                List<AddInventoryModel> refNumList = new List<AddInventoryModel>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    AddInventoryModel robj = new AddInventoryModel();
                    robj.referenceNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["num"].ToString();
                    refNumList.Add(robj);
                }
                Adi.refNumDD = refNumList;
            }
            connfb.Close();
```

**Model**

```
 public class AddInventoryModel
    {
    [Display(Name = "1. Reference Number: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Reference Number is required!")]
        public string referenceNumber { get; set; }

    public List<AddInventoryModel> refNumDD { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.referenceNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-100" })
        <div class="col-md-20">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.referenceNumber, new SelectList(Model.refNumDD, "referenceNumber"), "Choose reference number")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect overload of `SelectList` constructor.

Use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_)

```
public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, 
                   string dataValueField, 
                   string dataTextField);
```

The second parameter is the value field which will be used to set the OPTION value attribute value and the third parameter is the text filed which will be used to render the OPTION text.

Since your controller code is only setting the `referenceNumber` property on the
`AddInventoryModel` objects, you can use that for both dataTextField and dataValueField.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.referenceNumber, 
                       new SelectList(Model.refNumDD, "referenceNumber","referenceNumber"),
                       "Choose reference number")
```

*For rendering SELECT elements, I personally prefer to use a collection `SelectListItem` in my view model, instead of a collection of custom objects.*